# Weak convergence of functionals $g_n^*(f) = n\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, normed-spaces, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

> Show that sequnce of functionals $g_n^*(f) = n\displaystyle{\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx}, f \in C[0,1]$ converges weakly and find its limit functional. Does it converge in the norm of space $C^*[0,1]$?

I don't even know how to start, I guess I have to guess first which is limit functional, and then prove $g_n^*$ converges to it, but I don't have any idea what it could be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Justify the interchange of limits for $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} (n+1) \int_0^1 x^nP_m(x)dx$ where $P_m(x)$ is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4645940/justify-the-interchange-of-limits-for-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-lim-m)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding weak convergence - you want to prove that for any function $f\in C[0,1]$ the limit exists. One starts with $f$ being of the form $x^k$. It is easy to compute that $g_n(f) = \frac{n}{n+k}$ so the limit is $1$. Hence it is $f(1)$. Then, using linearity of $g_n$ one gets the same for $f(x) = \sum a_kx^k$ i.e. that the limit is $f(1)$. Then, by the fact that the norm of $g_n$ are bounded by 1 and density of polynomials in $C[0,1]$ one gets that the limit exists and is $f(1)$ for any continuous $f$. Lastly, since the limit is $f(1)$ it is just integral against measure with single atom at $1$.

Comment: You are proving strong convergence here, right? That $||g_n(f)-g(f)|| \to 0$, where $g(f)=f(1)$? Strong implies weak, so it's ok, but am I right?

Comment: No, I proved the weak convergence. The sequence of $g_n$ is NOT norm convergent. Sorry for the last statement ... it is not true. I do not know why I added it ...

Comment: I don't understand you now. Norm convergence means that $||g_n-g_0||_{(L^p)^*} \to 0$. How do you prove it doesn't hold? Strong convergence means that for every $f \in C[0,1], |g_n(f)-g_0(f)| \to 0$, and I think you proved that here. Weak convergence means that $f^*(g_n) \to f^*(g_0), \forall f^* \in (B(C[0,1],R)^*$. I think that this is not proved here.

Comment: No I proved weak convergence to the functional which sends $f$ to $f(1)$. There is no norm convergence otherwise we would have that $g_n -f(1)$ has norms convergent to $0$. But this is not the case for since value of this functional on functions which are $1$ on $[0,1-1/n]$ and then linear to $0$ is  separated from  $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof can be performed without applying the Weierstrass theorem. Instead we will base on the fact that $C^{2}[0,1]$ functions are dense in $C[0,1].$ Since the norms of the functionals are bounded it suffices to show the weak convergence holds for $C^2[0,1].$
Let $f\in C^2[0,1].$ Then applying the integration by parts two times we get
$$g_n^*(f)={n\over n+1}x^{n+1}f(x)\Big\vert_0^1-{n\over n+1}\int\limits_0^1x^{n+1}f'(x)\,dx\\
={n\over n+1}f(1)-{n\over (n+1)(n+2)}x^{n+2}f'(x)\Big\vert_0^1+{n\over (n+1)(n+2)}\int\limits_0^1x^{n+2}f''(x)\,dx\\
={n\over n+1}f(1)+O(n^{-1})$$ Therefore $g_n^*(f)\to f(1).$